# Angularjs Detect Link In TextArea & Preview

Tags: angularjs, url, textarea, preview

Are there any angular modules to detect a link in a textarea and then display the link in a preview area such as a div?

I have found a jquery approach here https://github.com/stephan-fischer/jQuery-LiveUrl but I'm interested in Angular.

Comment: Maybe using or looking into code of existing Angular-based editors. http://textangular.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can try Embed.ly module to do that (https://github.com/lithiumtech/angular-embedly). But for free its limit Up to 5,000 URLs per Month.